# How to change default input autofill color in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Just like in the title, I have regular TextInput and I would like to change the default yellow autofill color, I know it's possible in regular react-native by changing native android settings, but is there a way to do it in expo?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<TextInput style={{backgroundColor:"white"}} />
```